# Python : how to append a list (contained in a Main() program) from a file-module's function?

Tags: python

I started to code a text-based game in a
Main program which call functions in file-modules.

There is a particular case where a file-module and a function are called and the function (in the module) should append a list in the Main() program (a global variable).

The problem is it cannot append it.

So, more concretely, in the game, the player enters a room (RoomA2) and there’s an object (sword).
The player can pick it up  (and I want the function to remove it from the list called object_room_a2 ) and put the sword in his bag.
So, the bag is a global list (called object_list) in the Main() program.

Please the codes below, thanks for the help!

```
object_list = []

def main():
    print('stuff.. What do you want to do? (1) do this; (2) do that')
    choice = int(input('Choice --> '))

    if choice == 1 :
        RoomA2.room_a2()
    elif choice == 2 :
        RoomB1.room_b1()

def room_a2():
    object_room_a2 = ['sword']
    print('stuff.. What do you want to do? (1) do this; (2) do that')
    choix = int(input('choix --> '))

    if choix == 1:
        object_room_a2.remove('sword')
        object_list.append('sword')

    if choix == 2:
        RoomA1.room_a1()
```

Comment: Where's `RoomA1` etc..? What is your data-model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every time `room_a2` is called, `object_room_a2` is re-initialized so the sword will keep reappearing.

In general, this is a very complicated way to do what you are trying to do. A player object and a collection of room objects would make for far less code, but I assume that you are a beginner and might want to get a few rooms working this way first.

Comment: hI MSW! Thanks for your answer. Thats right Im a beginner. Funny because I am reading about object-classes programming in Python at this very moment. Will certainly apply that! cheers